# Proof of existence of the point

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis

Let $C$ be a *closed*, *convex* set and $x \notin C$. Then exists one and only one point $c \in C$ such that $\|x - c\| = min_{y \in C} \|x - y\| = d(x, C)$. 
The proof of uniqueness by *reductio ad absurdum* is clear. But the proof of existence confuses me. Namely, we take a $v \in C$ arbitrary and observe the set $$V = \{y \in C : \|x - y\| ≤ \|x - v\|\} = C \cap \bar{B}_{x-v}(x).$$I realize the set $V$ is *closed* and *convex* (as an intersection of such sets), but why is $V$ *compact*? Further, the proof observes $\phi : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R} , \phi(y) = \|x - y\|$ which is continuous on $V$, thus it reaches its minimum and the claim is proved. But why is $V$ **compact**?

Comment: Isn't it closed in the *compact ball* $\overline{B}_{x-v}(x)$, if I understand well the notations?

Comment: Oh, so $V$ is not compact, yet the part in the ball is compact and the minimum has to be there (it's obvious the minimum is in the ball)?

Comment: I'm guessing you're working in finite dimensions?

Comment: Yes. C is a subset of R^n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A closed subset of a compact set is always compact. So, $C$, being a closed set, intersects with $\overline{B}_{\|x - v\|}(x)$, which is a compact set, producing $V$, a closed subset of the compact set $\overline{B}_{\|x - v\|}(x)$, and hence is compact. So yes, $V$ is indeed compact.

Very similarly, you can also appeal to the [Heine-Borel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem). $V$ is the intersection of closed sets, and hence closed. Since it lies inside a closed ball, it is also bounded.